# UITabBarController Custom Button not hiding while moving to next ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have added custom center button in UITabBarViewController, code as below...

```
self.centerButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.centerButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
self.centerButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
[self.centerButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.centerButton setBackgroundImage:highlightImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

CGFloat heightDifference = buttonImage.size.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height;
  if (heightDifference < 0) {
        self.centerButton.center = self.tabBar.center;
  } else {
        CGPoint center = self.tabBar.center;
        center.y = center.y - heightDifference/2.0;
        self.centerButton.center = center;
  }

[self.centerButton addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:self.centerButton];
```

Please check attached screenshot for reference,

[image]

Now when I am trying to hide it while moving to other viewcontroller, only tabbar gets hidden and not the center custom button with below code,

```
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
```

Also tried like this to hide center custom button,

```
 WBTabBarController *objWBTab = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:ID_CNTRL_TABBAR];
 [objWBTab setTabBarHidden:YES];
```

SetTabBarHidden has been defined as below in WBTabBarController.m,

```
- (void)setTabBarHidden:(BOOL)tabBarHidden
{
    self.centerButton.hidden = tabBarHidden;
    self.tabBar.hidden = tabBarHidden;
}
```

Still no luck, can anybody help me please?

Comment: Why don't you just add the `UIButton` as a subview of the tab bar instead of `self.view`?

Comment: As custom button is bigger in height so I must have add it in self.view and I cant add it in tabbar

Comment: Well doesn't setting the clips to bounds to false of the tabbar do the same thing? Like the button can be visible outside the bounds of the tabbar

Comment: Ohhh yes. You are absolutely right. I tried this. But by adding it in tabbar.. My button is not showing any more. It would be great if you could help me somewhat more..

Comment: Okay okay.. I got it. Frame is creating issue. As such before it has been added in self.view and now it is inside tabar. So I need to modify frame logic a bit. Thanks a lot for your help! You saved my time. Thank you

Comment: Thats cause your frame is probably wrong of the `UIButton`.

Comment: Yes I did it. By correcting frame

Comment: any solution found to this?? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @HardikAmal Yes I solved it. You can refer above comments for solution, may be it could help you. Still you need any more help then let me know

Comment: @HardikAmal Even you can refer below accepted answer. This was the solution for me.

Comment: Can you share the frame logic... even my custom button is bigger in size then tabbar... and using below answer hides my custombutton...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you're adding your button as subview to your entire view instead of tabBar's view.

Change   `[self.view addSubview:self.centerButton];` line with
`[self.tabBar addSubview:self.centerButton];`

Comment: Custom button is not added in my bottomBar. It is added in self.view of tabbarviewcontroller. So if I am gonna hide bottombar still custom button will not be hidden. As custom button is bigger in height so I must have add it in self.view and I cant add it in tabbar

Answer (score 0):

Trying checking **Hide Bottom Bar** on Push for your **ViewController to be opened on storyboard** [image]

or you can also use it as this in programmatically approach

```
      self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
      let destinationVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryBoardID") as! yourVC
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
      self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Let try to hide it when view will disappear

```
-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
     [self setTabBarHidden:YES];
     [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

and show it when view will appear

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     [self setTabBarHidden:NO];
     [super viewWillAppear];
}
```

Comment: viewWillDisappear is not getting called while moving to other viewcontroller from tabbarcontroller :(